# Правописание НЕ и НИ с прилагательными, как разобраться?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Исправьте ошибки в данных примерах:

Коля специалист ни хороший ни плохой (НИ - правильно, знаки препинания?)

Петя не хороший, не плохой игрок (НЕ, а может НИ, запятая нужна?)

Саша не хороший и не плохой спортсмен (Правильно?)

Answer (score 2):

Предлагается такое решение:

Коля специалист ни хороший ни плохОй (обозначаем тесную связь определений, паузу не делаем, запятую не ставим, интонация простого предложения, ударение на втором определении).

Петя ни хорОший, ни плохОй игрок (каждое определение имеет ударение, ставится запятая, обозначающая паузу).

Саша не хороший и не плохой спортсмен (при наличии  одиночного союза И используем отрицание без усиления (частица НЕ), запятой нет).